# Powerpc gnu eabi register initialization

Tags: gnu, powerpc, eabi

I have created a minimal bare metal application that I am compiling with the codesourcery gnu powerpc eabi lite toolchain and loading on a powerPC target with a USB JTAG TAP.  The application is created from an assembly file used to configure hardware and set up registers for the eabi, a main.c file that contains an infinite loop, a linker script, and a Makefile.

I have found a good deal of documentation on startup code for the powerpc, register initialization for the eabi, and the gnu linker for creating the linker script and have tried to follow it closely.

I have the application compiling and running until it reaches main.  The problem I am having is when the assembly routines complete and an rfi is executed I see the PC transition to main() as expected.  However, executing the first instruction in main (lis r9, 0) results in an exception, 0x700 (invalid instruction or fp exception).

The assembly routine initially contained code to invalidate the L1 data and instruction caches and disable them then enable only the L1 instruction cache.  Suspecting some of that code was incorrect, I removed much of it and only have be bare minimum.

Could it be that I am missing a C runtime initialization step?  Any other ideas?  Thanks for your help in advance.

The assembly code now only consists of the following:

```
.text

    .global resetHandler
    .global _start
    .global __eabi

    .space(0x0100)     /* locate start at hreset vector */

_start:

    b resetHandler

    .space(0x3000)  /* locate the remainder past the exception vector space */

resetHandler:
    xor r3, r3, r3

    /* set SRR0 to main */
    addis r3,r0,main@h
    ori r3,r3,main@l
    mtspr srr0,r3

    /* save machine state register to srr1 */
    mfmsr r0
    mtspr srr1, r0

    xor r1, r1, r1
    lis r1, _stack_start@h
    addi r1, r1, _stack_start@l

    bl __eabi

    /* place the address of done in the link register */
    xor r3, r3, r3
    addis r3, 0, done@h
    ori r3, r3, done@l
    mtlr r3

    rfi

__eabi:
    addis r13,r0,_SDA_BASE_@h
    ori r13,r13,_SDA_BASE_@l
    addis r2,r0,_SDA2_BASE_@h
    ori r2,r2,_SDA2_BASE_@l
    blr

done:
    b .
```

The linker script follows:

```
OUTPUT_ARCH(powerpc)
ENTRY(resetHandler)
SEARCH_DIR(.)

MEMORY
{
  ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x000000, LENGTH = 1M
}

_STACK_SIZE = 8k;
_HEAP_SIZE = 32k;

SECTIONS
{
      .text :
      {
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata*)
      } >ram

      .data : ALIGN (8)
      {
        _final_data_start = .;
        *(.data)
        _final_data_end = .;
      } >ram

      .sdata    : { *(.sdata)   } >ram
      .sbss     : { *(.sbss)    } >ram
      .sdata2   : { *(.sdata2)  } >ram
      .sbss2    : { *(.sbss2)   } >ram

      .bss : ALIGN (8)
      {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        . = ALIGN (8);
        _ebss = .;
      } >ram

    .stack     :
    {
        _stack_end = .;
        . = . + _STACK_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(16);
        __stack = .;
    }

    .heap      : 
    {
        __heap = .;
        . = . + _HEAP_SIZE;
        . = ALIGN(16);
        _heap_end = .;
    }

    _stack_start = __stack;
    _heap_start = __heap;

    _SDA2_BASE_ = ADDR(.sdata2);
    _SDA_BASE_ = ADDR(.sdata);
}
```

Comment: Since it's been a while, I'm assuming you no longer need help with this?

Comment: Phonetagger, if you know something on it, please do tell us. I do need this info as of now. I am also trying to create a bare metal "app" to better understand powerpc assembly.